# Umbraco field in masterpage

Tags: umbraco

I want to add a field to the master page but does not show me this.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.Master>
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Umbraco.Field("temat")
@RenderBody()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your field recursive. The problem is, if it's on your masterpage and you use Umbraco.Field, it's looking for the field on the current node you're on - so if you're not on the node that has the property "temat", it won't show anything.

```
@Umbraco.Field("test", recursive: true)
```